# Different size of disk in disk management and my computer, after extend in Hyper-V

Tags: hard-drive, hyper-v, partition, extend

[image]I have a problem after live extend disk from Hyper-V on running machine.

I normally increase the disk size from Hyper-V (300GB->1.3TB), then on system using disk management for extend.

In this case, disk management size displayed is accurate (1.3 TB), but when viewing my computer explorer, disk is still 300 GB.

I was using diskpart and extend filesystem but doesn't work. Server was restarted too. Any ideas? It's WS 2019.

[image]

[image]

Comment: please add screenshots of affected drive in disk management

Comment: added to question

Comment: What type of underlying storage?

Comment: It's normal dynamic VHDX disk on local physical disk

Comment: Can you add output of `powershell get-vhd -path virtualdisk.vhdx` to your question ?

Comment: Ye. Now i see my problem. Path points to snapshot. Probably its problem.

Comment: Its was not problem. I uploaded photo

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Kc70.png

Comment: Downvoting. Learn not to post screenshots of a COMMAND LINE. Learn how copy/paste works for text.

Comment: It is also pretty unclear if your question is still open, or that you concluded something from the output in that screenshot.....

Comment: It is still open. The problem has not been solved

Comment: Did the `FileSize` in your picture not show the size that your VHDX has, (400207904768 =~ 370Gb )

Comment: did you reboot the whole server? what does diskpart tell moreover while using the disk utils did you reload the partion table? did you really extend the drive?

Comment: Yes. Server rebooted, diskpart shows good 1.4TB, and yes extend... on upload image in post